# How to simulate a column header click in devexpress xtraGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid, incremental-search

Hi I have a devexpress grid on the form. I enable the incremental search on one of the columns. But I find I need to click the column header each time when I perform one search. Is there a way to simulate such header or column click in grid control?

I also try in gridcontrol_keydown event to set the focused row, but this one only works for once, after performing one search, I need to click the column header or the column again, otherwise the incremental search doesn't work anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain which XtraGrid settings you are using to enable incremental search?

Comment: You can find the detailed explanation in this document: http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column (or cell) click is required only to set focus to the column under which you want to search data. It is possible to focus a column programmatically. Use the [ColumnView.FocusedColumn](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedColumntopic) property.